# Convert UserControls into a vector image and display it in WPF app

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to, say, copy and display a series of control elements elsewhere as a vector image, just like a thumbnail.

I use `ItemsControl` to show a series of `UserControls` using `Canvas` as a template panel. Each control is accepting events. I don't need any functionality on copied control images. Also, no need to save one as a file, but just like to show it.

I've been trying exporting the container as EMF and import it back as a vector image (using [XamlToys](http://xamltoys.codeplex.com/)). It works to some extent, but the exported image is followed by a white-filled background (hope it being transparent), and importing EMF again sounds tedious and troublesome.

Is there any neat way to do that?

For now, I am considering to directly use XAML to get a image passed to `drawingContext.DrawImage()` (not a concrete plan, though).

Comment: try saving/reading to/from xaml format, unless you really need an image.

Comment: "Is there any neat way to do that?" Yes, it's called `VisualBrush`.